# Сравнение списка методом For-Each

Tags: java, foreach

Нужно реализовать функцию, которая из элементов переданного списка целых чисел (List) составит новый список (List), состоящий из всех элементов списка за исключением локальных минимумов.
Будем считать что локальным минимумом - элемент соседи которого (элемент справа и слева; только справа для - [0]го элемента; только слева - для последнего элемента списка) строго больше заданного элемента.
Не обращаться к спискам по индексам, перебирать элементы только с помощью цикла For-Each

```
for (int value: list){...}
```

Пример:
{ 1, 2, 3, 5, -1, 0, 5, 3 } -> { 2, 3, 5, 0, 5}

У меня самого получилось реализовать только с помощью обычного цикла for и обращаясь к элементам по индексам

```
 public static void process(List<Integer> list) {

        List<Integer> listFinal = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int value = 0; value < list.size(); value++) {


            if (value == 0 && list.get(value + 1) < list.get(value)) {
                listFinal.add(list.get(value));
            }
            if (value > 0 && value < list.size() - 1) {
                if (list.get(value + 1) < list.get(value) || list.get(value - 1) < list.get(value)) {
                    listFinal.add(list.get(value));
                }
            }
            if (value == list.size() - 1 && list.get(value) > list.get(value - 1)) {
                listFinal.add(list.get(value));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(listFinal);
    }
```

Comment: Вам из цикла for нужно сделать foreach?

Comment: @Зонтик, for я выгрузил для примера работы кода, чтобы было понятно какие должны быть ответы. Нужно сделать всё через метод for-each( не обращаясь к спискам по индексам)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно завести 3 переменные `a,b,c`, которые будут последовательно заполняться числами из списка в цикле. Проверяем их и добавляем в итоговый список те числа, которые НЕ локальные минимумы. Особенности сравнения у первого и последнего числа.
Также вводим переменную `iter`, которая нужна, чтобы обеспечить первоначальную "загрузку" первых двух чисел из списка в переменные.

```
public class Main {
    public static void process(List<Integer> list) {

        List<Integer> listFinal = new ArrayList<>();
        int a, b = Integer.MIN_VALUE, c = Integer.MIN_VALUE, iter = 0;
        for (int n : list
        ) {
            a = b;
            b = c;
            c = n;
            if (iter < 2) {
                if (!(b < c)) listFinal.add(b);
                iter++;
            } else {
                if (!(b < a & b < c)) listFinal.add(b);
            }
        }
        if (!(c < b)) listFinal.add(c);

        System.out.println(listFinal);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        process(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 5, -1, 0, 5, 3));
    }
}
```

```
[2, 3, 5, 0, 5]
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать очередь ограниченного размера, в которой будут размещаться элементы исходного списка.  По мере прохождения по исходному списку, размер очереди будет поддерживаться не более 2 элементов.

Также по условию задачи метод `process` должен вернуть новый список без локальных минимумов:

```java
public static List<Integer> process(List<Integer> list) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    
    for (Integer n : list) {
        boolean empty = queue.isEmpty();
        queue.offer(n);
        if (!empty) {
            if (queue.size() < 3) {
                Integer prev = queue.peek();
                if (prev >= n) {
                    result.add(prev);
                }
            } else { // queue size should be 3 here
                Integer first = queue.poll();
                Integer prev = queue.peek();
                if (!(prev < first && prev < n)) {
                    result.add(prev);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (queue.size() == 2) {
        Integer first = queue.poll();
        Integer prev = queue.peek();
        if (prev >= first) {
            result.add(prev);
        }
    } else if (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        result.add(queue.poll());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Тест:

```java
List<List<Integer>> data = Arrays.asList(
    Arrays.asList(),
    Arrays.asList(22),
    Arrays.asList(1, 2),
    Arrays.asList(3, 2),
    Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 5, -1, 0, 5, 3)
);        
for (List<Integer> list : data) {
    System.out.println(list + " => " + process(list));
}

[] => []
[22] => [22]
[1, 2] => [2]
[3, 2] => [3]
[1, 2, 3, 5, -1, 0, 5, 3] => [2, 3, 5, 0, 5]
```